# Difference between flutter android and Ios app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am currently developing apps only for android using flutter. But if I want to run the same app on ios, what changes do I have to make?

Comment: Possibly nothing. Have you done anything specific to Android?

Comment: you might need to tweak around some files under the `ios` folder, e.g. info.plist, depending on the package you use.

Comment: @TedHenry I have configured flutter with firebase for fcm but nothing else. Does icons have anything to do with platform or is it just for the sake of looks and feels? I have seen people using icons (material for android and cupertino for ios) in videos.

Comment: You are not required to use different icons in iOS. The material icons appear in many apps in iOS. Notably the very popular apps from Google that are essential to modern mobile device use.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some platform specific plugins in your flutter app like firebase, you will have to do some additional setup for ios, but normally it would not be that much.